# I have created a portal to show a modal but its not showing

Tags: javascript, reactjs, portal

I have created a file in which I have a create portal

```
import React from "react"
import ReactDOM from "react-dom"


const ModalUI = (props) => {
   return (
      <div>
          <h1>hello world </h1>
      </div>
   )
 }


const Modal = (props) => {
   return (
      <div>
           {ReactDOM.createPortal(<ModalUI>{props.children}</ModalUI>, document.getElementById("overlay"))}
      </div>
  )
}
export default Modal;
```

and **index.html** are as

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <link rel="icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
  <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000" />
  <meta name="description" content="Web site created using create-react-app" />
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/logo192.png" />
  <!--
      manifest.json provides metadata used when your web app is installed on a
      user's mobile device or desktop. See https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/web-app-manifest/
    -->
  <link rel="manifest" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/manifest.json" />
  <!--
      Notice the use of %PUBLIC_URL% in the tags above.
      It will be replaced with the URL of the `public` folder during the build.
      Only files inside the `public` folder can be referenced from the HTML.

      Unlike "/favicon.ico" or "favicon.ico", "%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico" will
      work correctly both with client-side routing and a non-root public URL.
      Learn how to configure a non-root public URL by running `npm run build`.
    -->
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <title>React App</title>
</head>

<body>
  <noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
  <div id="overlay"></div>
  <div id="root"></div>
  <!--
      This HTML file is a template.
      If you open it directly in the browser, you will see an empty page.

      You can add webfonts, meta tags, or analytics to this file.
      The build step will place the bundled scripts into the <body> tag.

      To begin the development, run `npm start` or `yarn start`.
      To create a production bundle, use `npm run build` or `yarn build`.
    -->
</body>
</html>
```

its not showing at all

code error or mistake

Comment: Where are you using the `<Modal>` component?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

at the first you need to import Modal:

```
 import Modal from
```

then use Modal tag in your code

```
 <Modal 
   open=true
  >
  <div>
        <h1>hello world </h1>
    </div>
   </Modal>
```